# Mark inbox/notifications with date/time

Tags: feature-request

It gets confusing to look at the inbox/notifications and not knowing when a message was sent. Any particular reason why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the data time if you hover over the inbox. Displaying additional information will only clutter the display.
So, I believe there is no room for this request.

Comment: Hadn't noticed. Too little coffee...

Comment: @vonbrand well, no harm in asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try hovering over the link!

That or clicking it.

Comment: Sorry, can accept only one answer.

Comment: So you went for the guy who answered *after* me?

Comment: Yeah well, the OP needs to hover over the time to show the seconds... Oh... wait ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see the time when the messages were sent is going to the full inbox, which is part of the network profile. You have tab called "inbox" in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1914880/vonbrand) and there is a shortcut by scrolling to the bottom of the Multicollider's inbox and clicking "more inbox messages …".